# How do i label gem "Chartkick" y & x axis?

Tags: html, graph, chartkick

Does Chartkick allow users to label the x/y axies?

```
     Sample Code:
     <%= line_chart Product.group("purchased").maximum(:price) %>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, with Google Charts, use:

`<%= line_chart Product.group("purchased").maximum(:price), {library: {hAxis: {title: "X"}, vAxis: {title: "Y"}}} %>`

Comment: On a similar note, how do you set the height and width of the chart?

Comment: <%= line_chart Product.group("purchased").maximum(:price), {height: "400px", library: {hAxis: {title: "X"}, vAxis: {title: "Y"}}} %> is how you include the height...